# SQL End of table loop

Tags: php, sql

I'm attempting to create a small application which allows an infinite pagination like feature for my hobbyist website, this will show four different videos in a small list that people can choose to watch, they can then click the "next" button which shows the next 4 videos on the database.

What I'm wanting to do is make it so that at any given time the list of 4 videos is always full, however currently this is not the case, a standard select statement allows me to select 4 rows from the current one and display them on the website, however what I want to do is different.

I've been trying to find a way to make it so the SQL Query would return results from the top of the table if the bottom of the table was reached, say there was only 14 videos in my database, When the user hits "next" again, it should display the last two videos and the first two videos.

Is this possible to do with a single query, or would running multiple queries and logging down numbers be the only way to do it? I feel like I'm massively overthinking this.

Regards, Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `union` you can get the data. Try something like this. Here I am passing `@min`, `@take` from application. Tweak the query as per the requirement.

```
declare @min int = 1, @take int = 3

declare @table table(id int identity(1,1), name varchar(30))

insert into @table
select 'Mary' union
select 'John'union
select 'Steve' union
select 'Lisa' union
select 'Chris'

declare @count int = 0, @max int = 0, @take1 int = 0

select @max = @min + @take

select @count = count(1) from @table

if((@max-1) > @count)
    select @take1 = (@max -1) - @count

select top (@take) * from
(
    select row_number() over (order by id) RN, * from @table 
) main 
where rn between @min and @max

union

select top (@take1) * from
(
    select row_number() over (order by id) RN, * from @table 
) child
 where rn between 1 and @take1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are using. Limit and offset while hitting next. Similarly if the result set returned by the SQL query is none (I mean check it in php itself) then make the limit to 2 and offset to 1. It's just a simple way to achieve! Hope it helps

Comment: There's the obvious way of executing a query, counting the results, then executing another query with (limit - found) as the limit in another query, I'm just trying to figure out if there's a "Proper" way to do this with SQL

Comment: There's many ways to  achieve this without executing this in a query. It depends on what you want. For eg you can achieve this using jquery. If the result set is zero you can append the first tow repeating divs to the last. thus you're only showing the content from the previously acquired result. But only it can be achieve if you load via ajax. if you reload the page, how can you expect to acquire data without making a fresh request.